# Setting maxConcurrentOperationCount in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

So I have this code in a swift project:

```
self.operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()   
self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount(NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount)
```

This does not work. On the second line I get this error:

```
(Int) -> $T4 is not identical to 'Int'
```

How can I set the NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount on the opertaionQueue in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the header file for for `NSOperationQueue`:

```
var maxConcurrentOperationCount: Int
```

you'll see that `maxConcurrentOperationCount` is a property, not a method, so you'll need to use:

```
self.operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
self.operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount`